# What is the name of the trope where a character intends to do 'one last job' but get killed during this job?

Tags: trope

What is the name of the trope where a character intends to 'get out' after doing 'one last job' but gets killed during this job? I have found the [One Last Job](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OneLastJob) on TV Tropes, however it doesn't contain this specific scenario. It seems also somewhat related to the [If We Get Through This](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/IfWeGetThroughThis) trope.

Death by retirony is pretty close but I’m wondering if there’s anything in particular for dying on that particular last mission.

I don’t remember other concrete examples right now, but one where the character doesn’t die all the way but gets severely injured after forecasting this way is

> Kimiko in The Boys season 3 episode 4.

Comment: Seems pretty close to "Retirony" - in which they were just days from retirement even if it's not the exact same...

Comment: Not exactly the same is indeed what it is. There are plenty of tiny variations of all kinds of tropes.

Comment: Did you consider that this trope does not have a name?

Comment: In what way does "One Last Job" not "contain this specific scenario" ... seems exact enough to me.  This may account for why you are getting downvotes and "needs more focus" votes.

Comment: It might help if you can offer a concrete example from a reasonably well-known work.

Comment: I'm really puzzled as to what is being asked here, since it's not clear why "One Last Job" isn't close enough,  or indeed whether we should consider "naming of tropes" to even be on topic here.

Comment: @iandotkelly I understood them to be asking for a trope more narrow that "one last job" that specifies that the person doing the job is killed.

Answer (score 3):

This is a variant of "[one last job](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OneLastJob)." That trope description says:

> Usually, this leads to either a 10-Minute Retirement, or death by Retirony

Comment: Yeah it does seem to be in there somewhere. Just was looking for a more specific/detailed one but there may not be any

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek. So the only difference between "one last job" and your scenario is that they get killed, whereas "one last job" has other possible outcomes.  That's getting quite narrow even for a trope definition.

Comment: @iandotkelly I think that's right. Thats how I understood the question.

Comment: @iandotkelly yeah I meant that they get killed specifically during that job, not just from random bad luck or whatever event immediately afterwards